# Running into a problem when trying to upload a video to S3 through React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-s3, fetch

I was hoping to get some advice in regards to an error I'm getting with my approach. The error is `THE ERROR IS  [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<']`

Whenever the component mounts, I make sure to make a request for a presignedURL to my S3 server. Within a `useEffect` what I do currently is:

```
const getAwsUrl = async () => {
    getUrl().then((response) => {
        if (response.data) {
            const url = response.data.getSignedUrl.url;
            uploadFileToS3(url);
        }
    });
};

getAwsUrl();
```

The way I'm sending the file to the server is through a fetch. I am getting the error when returning a response but I'm also noticing that no video file is being uploaded to my S3.

```
const uploadFileToS3 = async (url) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', video.uri);

    await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
        .then((res) => console.log(res))
        .catch((e) => console.log('THE ERROR IS ', e));
};
```

Is there something wrong in the way I'm sending my information to S3?

Thank you for pointing out any mistakes that can be seen on my end.

**UPDATE**

The video.uri is just a path to where the video is located (within the phone)

Comment: What is `video.uri`?  And, somewhere you're expecting a JSON response, but you shouldn't because you won't get JSON from S3.

Comment: @Brad The video url is just the location where the video is catched after it's been stopped within Expo Camera. Two questions. What can be wrong that it's not sending the video to S3 (since I don't see it there) and second is if JSON isn't returned, what can we expect from S3? I am hoping we are getting a path in order to save it to the DB. Thank you for the help and response

Comment: You can't append a file to FormData by specifying it's URL.  You need to append the actual Blob or File reference.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append  As for S3's response, you know the path because S3 is only going to store things where you tell it to.  See also:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html  Additionally, if you're not actually using the form API, you'll want to be doing a PUT, with the appropriate headers.